# Read files from another pc Using JAVA and apache tomcat

Tags: java

```
File[] files = new File("\\172.22.1.77\FolderName").listFiles();
```

I'm trying to read some files from another IP on my network from shared folder 'FolderName'.

It works locally from eclipse.

But when it deployed on apache tomcat, it doesn't work.

Any help about this ?

Comment: In what way doesn't it work? Do you get any exceptions or is the array just empty?

Comment: no exception occur.. no result returned..

Answer (score 2):

Check if the user under which Tomcat is running has permissions to access the folder

Comment: my pc have the permissions.. how can give the permissions to the user under which Tomcat is running ??

Comment: Depends on the OS you're using.

Comment: Take a look at this:  http://superuser.com/questions/301864/run-tomcat-service-as-different-user-on-windows-7